# Storyboard partially crashes in Xcode 11 after selecting a segue

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode11

I'm migrating my project to iOS 13 using XCode 11. I have multiple storyboards and when I go to my main storyboard and select a certain Segue, the following error appears.

> KSCStoryboardMain.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for TableViewController (V5D-2k-w7k): The agent crashed

After that message, there is no way I can edit this specific view in the storyboard. I can edit other views, but not this one. In order to continue editing the view, I need to restart XCode.

I tried to select other segues, but it only appears in this specific table view. Also, on XCode 10.2.1, all works fine. It seems related to the UICollectionView that I have embedded in a UITableViewCell. There are no layout warnings for that view when I run the app. Does anyone have an idea where this error comes from and how to debug it?

Comment: The bug solved itself with new beta update of iOS 13. Must have been an issue on Apple side.